# How to print unicode codepoint?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, unicode, console

How can I print unicode codepoint as unicode character in C++ (gcc/clang) on Linux?
Let say I have something like this:

```
typedef uint32_t codepoint;
codepoint cp = somefunction();
```

How can I print cp as single unicode character? I have en_US.UTF-8 locale.

I've searched SO, I've tried:  wcout, wstring, wchar_t, setlocale, codecvt (no existent in gcc).

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you posted a short compilable example showing your attempts (my answer was based on a guess what you might have actually tried)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::wcout` in GNU has a [little quirk](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35353): while synchronized with C stdio, both C++ and C I/O subsystems need to be localized separately:

so either unsync

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::uint32_t n = 0x98A8;

    std::wcout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::wcout << wchar_t(n) << '\n';
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13b718ae11fa539e

or localize both

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
int main()
{
    std::uint32_t n = 0x98A8;

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::wcout << wchar_t(n) << '\n';
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b7d4547e1184ad

Comment: PS: this is naturally not portable to the system where `wchar_t` is less than 32-bit wide.. but that system doesn't have utf8 locales either.

Comment: clang is good. You don't need sync_with_studio, nor the setlocale(LC_ALL).

Comment: you can remove the "en_US.utf8", std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "") and std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("")) will set to system default locale.

Comment: @user534498 sure, although it depends on the exact meaning of 'having' the `en_US.utf8`.